# Unable to hit my struts 2 action class using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, maven

Hi I m trying to make a call to LoginAction.java from my jsp page    using jquery ajax function. My call is happening properly if i don't    pass any param with the ajax function and dont add param tag in    action of struts.xml But when i add a param which is of type object in ajax call and add param tag in struts action then my    LoginAction class is not being called or hit .
Thanks in advance.

```html
let email = $("email").val();
         let fName = $("fName").val();
         let lName = $("lName").val();
         let password = $("pwd").val();
         
         var newUser = new user(email,fName,lName,password);
         
         alert(newUser);
         
         $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:'register.action?user='+new?User,
                success: function(data){
                
                }});
```

struts.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" extends="json-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="register" class="com.blogger.action.LoginAction" method="register">
            <param name = "user">${user}</param>
            <result name="SUCCESS" type="json"></result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

LoginAction.java:

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String register() {
        System.out.println("in register function");
        User newU = user;
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ajax syntax which I was writing was wrong . It had to be like the one below.

```
    let email = $("#email").val();
let fName = $("#fName").val();
let lName = $("#lName").val();
let password = $("#pwd").val();

alert(email+" "+fName+" "+lName+" "+password);
var newUser = JSON.stringify({userList:new user(email,fName,lName,password)});

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'register.action',
    data : {userList : newUser},
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){

    }
    });
```

And my struts.xml should have contained param tag as below.

```
<action name="register" class="com.blogger.action.LoginAction" method="register">
        <param name="userList">userList</param>
        <result name= "success" type="json"></result>
    </action>
```